# Is $X_{1}^2 +2X_{2} - \sin(X_{3})$ measurable w.r.t to $\sigma(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables

I am just learning about $\sigma$-field and I came across this exercise in my worksheet. The answer says True but it's not quite obvious to me. How do I solve this?

Comment: $f(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma (X_1,X_2,X_3)$ for any meaurable function $f: \mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb R$. Any continuous function $f: \mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb R$ is measurable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks can you give a case for which it may not be measurable? Perhaps I can understand it better